# MondoDB Atlas stuck after few minutes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, react-apollo

I building a MERN app with MongoDB atlas, mongoose and apollo. It worked well until few days ago. Since when I start the server it works fine for a few minutes then its spend ages with every database task. If I restart the server it works again for some minutes.

My consoles right after server start and login:

[Browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFbZ3.png)
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdYqE.png)

After 10 minutes and a logout( it's uses window.location.reload() ) the same consoles:

[Browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn9dZ.png)
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qz8y.png)

(The data what the logs refers to is my main page's content.)

Anybody met with a problem like this.
Should I use local db instead cloud or any other suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide server outputs or logs?

Comment: Yes it logs before the task (e.g. await User.findOne()) then it stuck and if I have some luck after some minutes it log after the task, but sometimes it doesn't reach the console log and the client reports network error

Comment: So edit your question with logs and outputs in order we know what happened